# How do I get to meta on Spanish Language and Usage

Tags: support

In the past, I had a button marked "Meta" along the top line button bar when I was in Spanish Language and culture.  That top line is the one that has "Stackexchange" on the left.

Now, I don't see that button anymore.  It looks like an accident, but I'm not sure.
Is this intentional?  Is it due to an error beyond my control?  Is it due to something I'm doing wrong?  Is there another way to get there?

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot? I still see `meta` links on beta sites just fine; it's there on Spanish too but I'm not logged in.

Comment: I no longer need this to be solved.  I use the clickable navigator on the left of the top bar.  This is labelled "StackExchange" with a down arrow next to it.  That gives me the navigation tool I want.

Comment: Yes, the meta link was moved into that menu when that menu was redesigned.

Answer (score 6):

The link *should* be right up in the top bar:

[image: Meta <3 FHC]

If you don't see that, please provide a screen capture.

Per-site metas always have a URL with `meta.` prepended to the main site's domain name.

So the URL is: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/